MariaDB completely stuck, can only kill process, what might have happened?
Saturday morning 6:30 I'm getting phone calls that "the server" is down. This thing runs a webserver and various other services, all of which were non-responsive. It turned out that the MariaDB service had gotten hung up, "top" showed it churning at 180% CPU usage, and it didn't accept any connections. After I lost patience waiting for systemctl restart mariadb I just did a kill -KILL, restarted the service, and everything was back to normal.
Now I'm trying to find out what happened. The problem seems to have started at about the same time as the execution of /etc/cron.daily. Timeline:
03:34 Start of database backups using mysqldump (my own script, dumping DBs into individual files)
03:39:23 Timestamp of last dumped file
03:39:48 Timestamp of rotated logfile /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log-20240615
03:41:00 Timestamp of a committed DB entry
From then on, silence in logfiles (also journalctl) until I killed and restarted the server
So the last thing that was "done" to the DB server seems to have been logrotate which uses a kill -1 command to make the server start a new logfile.
Any clues what might have happened here? For now I've disabled my custom backup script; I'll try and replicate the backup / rotate combo by hand on Monday.
[EDIT]
Of course I immediately checked the logfiles. Forgot to include them hereThere was literally nothing:
$ journalctl -u mariadb
-- Logs begin at Thu 2024-06-13 12:29:06 CEST, end at Mon 2024-06-17 08:21:22 CEST. --
Jun 13 12:29:12 d...com systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
Jun 13 12:29:14 d...com systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3 database server.
Jun 15 06:51:34 d...com systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.3 database server...
Jun 15 06:56:35 d...com systemd[1]: mariadb.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Skipping SIGKILL.
Jun 15 06:57:34 d...com systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jun 15 06:57:34 d...com systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jun 15 06:57:34 d...com systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.3 database server.
Jun 15 06:58:04 d...com systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3 database server...
Jun 15 06:58:04 d...com systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3 database server.

This is /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log-20240615. The first warning line is the last of several which I find in all log files. Not connected to the problem at hand. I don't understand any of the pages of summary following that, but I find no hint at an actual error.
The log file with date stamp 20240615 was created by logrotate.
2024-06-15  1:06:17 14910 [Warning] Aborted connection 14910 to db: 'xx' user: 'xx' host: 'xx.com' (Got timeout reading communication packets)

Status information:

Current dir: /sdb1/mysql/
Running threads: 26  Cached threads: 11  Stack size: 299008

Key caches:
default
Buffer_size:     134217728
Block_size:           1024
Division_limit:        100
Age_threshold:         300
Partitions:              0
blocks used:            22
not flushed:             0
w_requests:              0
writes:                  0
r_requests:           6308
reads:                  40


handler status:
read_key:    484542690
read_next:  2867172626
read_rnd    76146039145
read_first:       4540
write:          104301
delete            5871
update:        1660252

Table status:
Opened tables:        698
Open tables:          358
Open files:            67
Open streams:           0

Alarm status:
Active alarms:   0
Max used alarms: 0
Next alarm time: 0

Memory status:
Non-mmapped space allocated from system: 618389504
Number of free chunks:                   3646
Number of fastbin blocks:                72
Number of mmapped regions:               26
Space in mmapped regions:                280973312
Maximum total allocated space:           0
Space available in freed fastbin blocks: 5248
Total allocated space:                   36420688
Total free space:                        581968816
Top-most, releasable space:              17358192
Estimated memory (with thread stack):    910426112
Global memory allocated by server:       286054216
Memory allocated by threads:             2107432



Events status:
LLA = Last Locked At  LUA = Last Unlocked At
WOC = Waiting On Condition  DL = Data Locked

Event scheduler status:
State      : INITIALIZED
Thread id  : 0
LLA        : n/a:0
LUA        : n/a:0
WOC        : NO
Workers    : 0
Executed   : 0
Data locked: NO

Event queue status:
Element count   : 0
Data locked     : NO
Attempting lock : NO
LLA             : drop_schema_events:389
LUA             : drop_schema_events:391
WOC             : NO
Next activation : never

Contents of /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb:
/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log {
        create 600 mysql mysql
        su mysql mysql
        notifempty
        daily
        rotate 14
        missingok
        compress
        delaycompress
    postrotate
        # just if mysqld is really running
        if [ -e /run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ]
        then
           kill -1 $(</run/mariadb/mariadb.pid)
        fi
    endscript
}


Where is that? Not in /var/log/mariadb. And there are some files with "log" in the name in the /var/lib/mysql dir, but they are binaries. Where would the error log be?

journalctl -u mariadb.service

I checked both journalctl -u mariadb and /var/log/mariadb/... -- nothing. See edits in my original post.
